# oracle contains method is not supporting wildcard(%) inside {}

Tags: oracle, search

I am trying to use contains method for oracle text search.

1) I am using {} inside contains method to avoid special characters search but it's also not supporting %, I am mentioning query below:-

so, how do I search with % in contains method and also supporting special character search.

It is searching string zoo~om when i use given below query:-

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CONTAINS(NAME1,'{zoo~om}')>0;
```

but it's not working with %

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CONTAINS(NAME1,'{%oo~om}')>0;
```

Comment: Isn't a `%` at the beginning redundant anyway? Or did you mean to match an actual `%` in the text?

Comment: no it's a wildcard character in oracle

Comment: Similar question:-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30194480/oracle-text-escaping-with-curly-braces-and-wildcards?rq=1