# Oracle Contains statement with special characters

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I would like to search for this string 'A&G BROS, INC.' using oracle contains statement

```
  FROM contact
WHERE CONTAINS 
(name, 'A&G BROS, INC.') > 0
```

But I do not get accurate results I get over 300,000 records basically anything containing INC.
I tried escaping the & char using

```
  FROM contact
WHERE CONTAINS 
(name, 'A&' || 'G BROS, INC.') > 0
```

I still get same massive results
Any idea how to run this query with this special chars I want to narrow the results down so I can al least get results that starts with "A&G" Note "LIKE" and "INSTR" cannot be used.

Comment: Why can't you use LIKE nor INSTR? `... where instr(name, 'A&G BROS, INC.') > 0` should do.

Comment: I want take advantage of indexed columns

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30194480/oracle-text-escaping-with-curly-braces-and-wildcards

Answer (score 1):

The `&` is [AND](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ccref/oracle-text-CONTAINS-query-operators.html#GUID-65E581D8-41CD-4370-8EB5-EBC6FD81464D), but the `,` is also [ACCUM](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ccref/oracle-text-CONTAINS-query-operators.html#GUID-1F2C4D0C-1DE4-48E4-8A59-DDF21290EC50). The behaviour of those operators explains what you are seeing.

You need to [escape those characters](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ccref/special-characters-in-oracle-text-queries.html#GUID-F94D663C-6CE6-4FB0-AA4A-3AAEFF2E66D3):

> To query on words or symbols that have special meaning in query expressions such as and & or| accum, you must escape them. There are two ways to escape characters in a query expression...

So you could do:

```
  FROM contact
WHERE CONTAINS 
(name, 'A\&G BROS\, INC.') > 0
```

or

```
  FROM contact
WHERE CONTAINS 
(name, 'A{&}G BROS{,} INC.') > 0
```

or

```
  FROM contact
WHERE CONTAINS 
(name, '{A&G BROS, INC.}') > 0
```

---

If you can't stop your client prompting for substitution variables - which is really a separate issue to the `contains` escapes - then you could combine this with your original approach:

```
  FROM contact
WHERE CONTAINS 
(name, '{A&' || 'G BROS, INC.}') > 0
```

Comment: Thank you Alex for you response, I have tried all three of you suggestions I get no results at all.

Comment: You tagged it as Apex, so I assume you aren't actually running in a client that has at some point prompted you for a substitution variable value for `G`?

Comment: I am running it on Toad and actually it does prompt me for value for G then I just pick the run literal option

Comment: In SQL\*Plus you can `set define off`, so don't know if Toad has an equivalent. Or you can do your original 'escape' by splitting the string after the `&`.

Comment: it seems ` set define off ` not working in Toad

Comment: @zacki987 - I don't use Toad, but [from here](https://support.quest.com/toad-for-oracle/kb/4234144/toad-prompts-for-amp-substitution-variable-from-glogin-script), maybe try "View->Toad Options that the checkbox for prompt for substitution variables is turned off under Execute/Compile section."

Answer (score 1):

Another way to deal with the special characters is to use the function CHR(n), where n is the ASCII value of the special character. For &, it is 38, so instead of
'A&G BROS, INC.' you can use 'A'||CHR(38)||'G BROS, INC.'
Using these special characters directly in literals can be tricky, because they can behave differently in different environments.
You can find the ASCII value of a character using the ASCII function, like this:

select ascii('&') from dual;

### ASCII('&')

```
    38
```